# What is a common way to denote first and last vertices of the path $P$

Tags: graph-theory

What is a common way to denote first and last vertices of the path $P$ in a graph?
For example I have a path $P = v_1,v_2,...,v_k$ and I want to show the first vertex $v_1$ without using the $v_1$ symbol - something like that: $first(P)$ or $s(P)$.

So, what is a common practice to do this? (the same about the last vertex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$first(P)$ and $s(P)$ are certainly not common. However, the most important thing is that your notation is clear to the reader (i.e. has been defined).

The notation $v_0,v_1,...,v_n$ is common, where $n$ is often replaced with $k$. For instance, if you say, the graph $P=v_0,v_1,...,v_n$, it is clear to the reader that $v_0$ and $v_n$ are the first and last vertices. However, you can also say "The first vertex $v_0$ of some path $P$", and again it is clear what you are saying. Sometimes a few words are more informative (and even concise) than lots of symbols.

Comment: So, if I want to say that two paths $P_1$ and $P_2$ have the same first vertex, it's better say this in words? But I use this property quite often, maybe I can use some notations, just to reduce the text size, and if I do so, what notation would be clearer to the reader?

Comment: It depends somewhat on the context, but yes, you could say "the first vertex v_0 of each of the paths $P_1$ and $P_2$". If the numbering of the paths doesn't matter and you want to be even clearer, perhaps "the first vertex $v_0$ of the two paths $P_i=v_0,v_1,...,v_i$ and $P_j=v_0,v_1,...,v_j$". These are just two possibilities. If you are only going to refer to the (shared) first vertex of the paths, you could even use just $u$ or $v$ (both common letter choices for vertices). The most important thing is that it is clear to the reader what you mean.